# How to get localized short day-in-week name (Mo/Tu/We/Th...)

Tags: java, calendar, java-time, dayofweek, weekday

Can I get localized short day-in-week name (Mo/Tu/We/Th/Fr/Sa/Su for English) in Java?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The best way is with java.text.DateFormatSymbols

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("it"));
// for the current Locale :
//   DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(); 
String[] dayNames = symbols.getShortWeekdays();
for (String s : dayNames) { 
   System.out.print(s + " ");
}
// output :  dom lun mar mer gio ven sab
```

Comment: Be aware that the dayNames array will contain 8 elements, the first being an empty string, so the array can be directly indexed with a day number where Sunday is 1 and Saturday is 7.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 39):

If standard abbreviations are fine with you, just use Calendar class like this:

```
myCal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);
```

Comment: This is the decent way to get it.

Comment: Internally Calendar anyway calls DateFormatSymbols.getShortWeekdays.

Comment: simple way. cooool

Answer (score 28):

An example using SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date now = new Date();
// EEE gives short day names, EEEE would be full length.
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US); 
String asWeek = dateFormat.format(now);
```

SimpleDateFormat as been around longer than the C-style String.format and System.out.printf, and I think you'd find most Java developers would be more familiar with it and more in use in existing codebases, so I'd recommend that approach.

Comment: Isn't this the best answer?

Answer (score 13):

## java.time

Update for those using Java 8 and later.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");

Instant instant = Instant.now();

ZonedDateTime zDateTime = instant.atZone(zoneId);

DayOfWeek day = zDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
```

Show output.

```
System.out.println(day.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US));
System.out.println(day.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, Locale.US));
```

When run. See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/XZgcJu).

> Tue
>
> T

Answer (score 11):

### [`DateTimeFormatter#localizedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#localizedBy(java.util.Locale))

Starting with **Java SE 10**, you can use [`DateTimeFormatter#localizedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#localizedBy(java.util.Locale)).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfHindi = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E").localizedBy(Locale.forLanguageTag("hi"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtfBangla = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E").localizedBy(Locale.forLanguageTag("bn"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtfGerman = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E").localizedBy(Locale.forLanguageTag("de"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtfEnglish = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E").localizedBy(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));

        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable timezone e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.println(dtfHindi.format(today));
        System.out.println(dtfBangla.format(today));
        System.out.println(dtfGerman.format(today));
        System.out.println(dtfEnglish.format(today));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
शुक्र
শুক্র
Fr.
Fri
```

Alternatively, starting with **Java SE 8**, you can use [`DayOfWeek#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) with the applicable `Locale`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable timezone e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.println(today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.forLanguageTag("hi")));
        System.out.println(today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.forLanguageTag("bn")));
        System.out.println(today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.forLanguageTag("de")));
        System.out.println(today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.forLanguageTag("en")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
शुक्र
শুক্র
Fr.
Fri
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with the Calendar class (unless you write your own), but you can with the Date class. (The two are usually used hand-in-hand).

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar nowCal = Calendar.getInstance(); // a Calendar date
    Date now = new Date(nowCal.getTimeInMillis()); // convert to Date
    System.out.printf("localized month name: %tB/%TB\n", now, now); 
    System.out.printf("localized, abbreviated month: %tb/%Tb\n", now, now); 
    System.out.printf("localized day name: %tA/%TA\n", now, now);
    System.out.printf("localized, abbreviated day: %ta/%Ta\n", now, now); 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
localized month name: June/JUNE 
localized, abbreviated month: Jun/JUN 
localized day name: Friday/FRIDAY 
localized, abbreviated day: Fri/FRI
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
public String getDayString(){
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    DayOfWeek day = date.getDayOfWeek();
    return day.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale);
}
```

The result will be: **Monday**

Answer (score 0):

```
//you need to use joda library           
List<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] days = new String[7];
int a=2; 
//a =starting day of week 1=sunday ,2=monday
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");   
c2.set((Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK),a); 
int maxDay = c2.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
for(int i=0;i<maxDay;i++)
{                 
   days[i] = df.format(c2.getTime());
   c2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   String dayOfWeek = new LocalDate( days[i]).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText();
   dayList.add(dayOfWeek);         
}            
for(int i=0;i<maxDay;i++)
{
    System.out.print(" '"+dayList.get(i)+"'");
}
```