# How to check given timestamp is weekend?

Tags: java, date

Can anyone help me to complete this function in Java? thanks

```
// e.g. "20130218001203638"
boolean isWeekend(String date)
{
    ... ...
}
```

Find a post giving the exact answer I want.

[Check A Date String If Weekend In Java](https://helloacm.com/check-a-date-string-if-weekend-in-java/)

Comment: Lookup calendar & date classes. I think Calendar  since date got deprecated

Comment: See Calendar class 4 clues

Comment: That string can be parsed into a `Calendar` using a `DateFormatter` (IIRC). A `Calendar` can tell you the day of the week.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java example to get all weekend dates in a given month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272454/java-example-to-get-all-weekend-dates-in-a-given-month)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get localized short day-in-week name (Mo/Tu/We/Th...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790954/how-to-get-localized-short-day-in-week-name-mo-tu-we-th)

Answer (score 5):

`Calendar#get(DAY_OF_WEEK)` it  return values SUNDAY, MONDAY, ...

what you can just conditionally check with `Calendar.SATURDAY or Calendar.SUNDAY`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

```
boolean isWeekend = false;
Date date = new Date();
//assuming your date string is time in long format, 
//if not then use SimpleDateFormat class
date.setTime(Long.parseLong("20130218001203638"));
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);

if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY ||
         calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){
    isWeekend = true;
}
return isWeekend;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as date calculation is wearisome

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date d = df.parse(date);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
int wday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
return wday == Calendar.SATURDAY || wday == Calendar.SUNDAY;
```